# How to get results from OSQL.exe without dash characters from the command line?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, osql

Is there a way to send a osql query from the command line that returns results that do not include the big long line of dash characters that represent the column width?

Here is the sample code I am working with:

```
echo.
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\%SQLVER%\Tools\BINN\osql" -S . -E -Q "SELECT name + ', ' FROM sysdatabases order by name for XML PATH('')"
```

And the results look something like this:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 master, model, msdb, openfire, tempdb,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`-h-1` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012(SQL.80).aspx) to suppress headers: the dashes are the header/data separator "line"

The same switch can be used for sqlcmd too

Comment: That is the answer but it still leaves a huge blank footer of whitespace after the result. Any way to trim that?

Comment: @djangofan: yes, you need to CAST to varchar because you actually have xml datatype output. Sorry, I can't test right now, you'll have to play around a bit, perhap use a derived table or CTE

Comment: ok, thanks.  i got it:   SELECT CAST(name AS VARCHAR(30)) FROM sysdatabases

Comment: Turns out, I also need to precede the select statement with:  SET NOCOUNT ON;  as well as the -h switch.